# Record visibility issue : Production

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have to add three `LineItems` as default `LineItems` apart from existing `LineItems` for every `Item`(Almost for 500 Items). For the same purpose I have written a script to `insert` the `LineItems` and running that script from anonymous window as `System Administrtor`. The `LineItems` are getting `inserted`. As a `System Administrtor` I'm able to see inserted values(three default `LineItems`) along with existing `LineItem`, but the inserted values(three default `LineItems`) are not visible to users who created the `Item` and `LineItem`.

Comment: Are these custom objects? Are they in a master-detail or lookup relationship?

Comment: Yes sir, These are custom objects with Lookup relationship.

Comment: Confused. If you inserted the 3 line items then you are the one who inserted them and since you can see them the comment of "are not visible to users who created the item and line item" does not make sense as you said you can see them.

Comment: @Eric  Since I'm the Admin, I can login as any user to verify record visibility. So as Admin I'm able to see inserted record and also as admin I'm running the script to insert data because end user don't have permission once they are done with creation  `Items` and `LineItems `. So in current scenario the end user can't create record any more and now client wants to add some default values.

Answer (score 3):

First you will see the default owd of the object using security settings. If the object owd is private only owner of the record and users higher in the role hierarchy (assuming assign hierarchy is checked) can be see the record .

You will need to create share records of the owd is private .

If owd is controlled by parent ,the parent record needs to be shared via creating share records.